# ¿Como crear una trama (mosaico) a partir de un vector para usarlo como background?

Tags: android-studio, android-drawerlayout

Aplicaciones como WhatsApp usan como fondo un mosaico agradable. Busco hacer algo similar. En Illustrator cree un vector, pero lo que no se es como crear un drawable que pueda utilizar como background en un layout.

Gracias d antemano ✌

Answer (score -1):

Hola una vez que tengas la imagen del mosaico agregada a la carpeta drawable tenes que crear un drawable de extension .xml que sera el mosaico

debe tener algo como esto:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/patron_a_repetir"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

El tileMode con repeat como parametro es lo que hara que se repita el patron cuando lo uses como background

Comment: Gracias, probaré!!

Comment: Cuando probé esto en android 4.4.2 funciono, pero en android 6 me daba error, me cerraba la app. Supongo q habrá otro método mas compatible